# Sklearn complains about one-column dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Consider the following minimal example:

```py
from time import sleep  # To (try to) get warnings printed at the right places

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
mlp = MLPClassifier(tol=10)
dummy = DummyClassifier(strategy='uniform')

for size in [1, 2]:

    input_columns = [0, 1]
    output_columns = [j + 2 for j in range(size)]

    print('Dimension of output: ', len(output_columns))  # Is 1 or 2

    X = df[input_columns]
    Y = df[output_columns]

    print('MLPClassifier')
    mlp.fit(X, Y)
    sleep(3)

    print('DummyClassifier')
    dummy.fit(X, Y)
    sleep(3)

    print('\n\n\n')
```

At the first iteration, during the training of the MLPClassifier, Sklearn complains:

> lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py:934: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
>     y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

The second iteration runs fine. The DummyClassifier (`dummy.fit`) runs fine in both iterations.

The error is because I'm trying to send a one-column dataframe (`Y`) to `mlp.fit`. It doesn't happen on the second iteration, where `Y` is a two-column dataframe.

The question is: how can I properly pass the data to `fit` in the case of MLPClassifier? I've learned I can do `Y = Y.values.ravel()`, which works when the dataframe is one-column, but then it doesn't work for two-column dataframes. I'm looking for a consistent way to solve this generically for any number of columns.

Comment: Not sure if I understand why your Y would have two columns for a classification task?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is checking if the number of columns ==1 beforehand.

```
    if len(output_columns) == 1:
        mlp.fit(X, Y.values.ravel())
    else:
        mlp.fit(X, Y)
```